# Where is the value of `this` saved in prototype methods of constructor function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why `this` can be accessed inside both a constructor function and its prototype method. I know `this` will implicitly become an object when a constructor function is invoked with `new`, but I don't understand why `this` can be accessed in the prototype method as following:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.hi = function () {
  console.log(`Hi! My name is ${this.name}.`);
};

const john = new Person('john')
john.hi() //Hi! My name is john.
```

Is the `this` saved somewhere in global to that instance and its methods?

Comment: `this` is decided at *call time*. In `a.b()`, `this` inside `b` is `a`, that’s basically the rule.